# How to call javascript library in anime.js?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg, anime.js

The last few days I've been working with SVG animations starting with  and realizing that it doesn't come with everything I need.

I googled around for different SVG path animations and stumbled upon anime.js and their 'seemingly' easy SVG motion path. Checking the [codepen](https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/dXNgVB) and copying the code along with downloading the library unfortunately didn't work. 
I can't see the square, and if I try my best to make it visible it doesn't move at all. Now mind that I rarely work with libraries and the standard on how it works, I have no clue of.

Countless others have had the same problem and it's been easily fixed with a simple onload.window function or switching where they call the anime.min.js have solved most of them. But not for me. Either the library is outdated or I'm missing something obvious. (Most likely the latter ... )

```
Full HTML

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>SVG line drawing | anime.js</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
maximum-scale=1">
      <script src="anime-master/anime.min.js"></script>
      <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
            <section>
                    <article>
                      <svg width="256" height="112" viewBox="0 0 256 112">
                        <path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" d="M8,56 C8,33.90861 25.90861,16 48,16 C70.09139,16 88,33.90861 88,56 C88,78.09139 105.90861,92 128,92 C150.09139,92 160,72 160,56 C160,40 148,24 128,24 C108,24 96,40 96,56 C96,72 105.90861,92 128,92 C154,93 168,78 168,56 C168,33.90861 185.90861,16 208,16 C230.09139,16 248,33.90861 248,56 C248,78.09139 230.09139,96 208,96 L48,96 C25.90861,96 8,78.09139 8,56 Z"/>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="green"></div>
                    </article>
            </section>
      <script>
      var path = anime.path('path');

      anime({
        targets: 'div',
        translateX: path,
        translateY: path,
        rotate: path,
        duration: 3000,
        loop: true,
        easing: 'linear'
      });

      anime({
        targets: 'path',
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 6000,
        loop: true,
        direction: 'alternate',
        easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
      });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: .5rem;
  left: .5rem;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

Now as I mentioned I've tried calling the library everywhere on the page. In head, last in body (yeah I know, I had to), above the JavaScript < script >.

I get no errors in console and I can view the anime.min.js through developer sources.

I'm stuck and I've done as much googling as I've could. Can anyone guide me in the right direction so that I can keep working on this?

UPDATE: Still trying to fix this. I've tried using different examples such as the [SVG Path Animation](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/blob/master/documentation/examples/anime-svg-path-animation.html) and I got it to work, so I'm pretty sure I'm calling the library in the right place. But the SVG motion path still doesn't work. I posted this question yesterday and got zero responses, hopefully this bumps it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the external files as well.

while copying from codepen, make sure to include the external script files.

You can see a settings icon. Clicking it will show you if there is any external file linked or not. So don't forget to include it.

[image]

Here, you included the external js file but missed the external css file.

[image]

```js
// IE cannot apply CSS transforms on SVG elements. (See https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811744/ie11-bug-with-implementation-of-css-transforms-in-svg)
/*
 * Anime v1.1.2
 * http://anime-js.com
 * JavaScript animation engine
 * Copyright (c) 2016 Julian Garnier
 * http://juliangarnier.com
 * Released under the MIT license
 */

(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define([], factory);
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    // Browser globals (root is window)
    root.anime = factory();
  }
}(this, function () {

  var version = '1.1.2';

  // Defaults

  var defaultSettings = {
    duration: 1000,
    delay: 0,
    loop: false,
    autoplay: true,
    direction: 'normal',
    easing: 'easeOutElastic',
    elasticity: 400,
    round: false,
    begin: undefined,
    update: undefined,
    complete: undefined
  }

  // Transforms

  var validTransforms = ['translateX', 'translateY', 'translateZ', 'rotate', 'rotateX', 'rotateY', 'rotateZ', 'scale', 'scaleX', 'scaleY', 'scaleZ', 'skewX', 'skewY'];
  var transform, transformStr = 'transform';

  // Utils

  var is = {
    arr: function(a) { return Array.isArray(a) },
    obj: function(a) { return Object.prototype.toString.call(a).indexOf('Object') > -1 },
    svg: function(a) { return a instanceof SVGElement },
    dom: function(a) { return a.nodeType || is.svg(a) },
    num: function(a) { return !isNaN(parseInt(a)) },
    str: function(a) { return typeof a === 'string' },
    fnc: function(a) { return typeof a === 'function' },
    und: function(a) { return typeof a === 'undefined' },
    nul: function(a) { return typeof a === 'null' },
    hex: function(a) { return /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(a) },
    rgb: function(a) { return /^rgb/.test(a) },
    hsl: function(a) { return /^hsl/.test(a) },
    col: function(a) { return (is.hex(a) || is.rgb(a) || is.hsl(a)) }
  }

  // Easings functions adapted from https://jqueryui.com/

  var easings = (function() {
    var eases = {};
    var names = ['Quad', 'Cubic', 'Quart', 'Quint', 'Expo'];
    var functions = {
      Sine: function(t) { return 1 - Math.cos( t * Math.PI / 2 ); },
      Circ: function(t) { return 1 - Math.sqrt( 1 - t * t ); },
      Elastic: function(t, m) {
        if( t === 0 || t === 1 ) return t;
        var p = (1 - Math.min(m, 998) / 1000), st = t / 1, st1 = st - 1, s = p / ( 2 * Math.PI ) * Math.asin( 1 );
        return -( Math.pow( 2, 10 * st1 ) * Math.sin( ( st1 - s ) * ( 2 * Math.PI ) / p ) );
      },
      Back: function(t) { return t * t * ( 3 * t - 2 ); },
      Bounce: function(t) {
        var pow2, bounce = 4;
        while ( t < ( ( pow2 = Math.pow( 2, --bounce ) ) - 1 ) / 11 ) {}
        return 1 / Math.pow( 4, 3 - bounce ) - 7.5625 * Math.pow( ( pow2 * 3 - 2 ) / 22 - t, 2 );
      }
    }
    names.forEach(function(name, i) {
      functions[name] = function(t) {
        return Math.pow( t, i + 2 );
      }
    });
    Object.keys(functions).forEach(function(name) {
      var easeIn = functions[name];
      eases['easeIn' + name] = easeIn;
      eases['easeOut' + name] = function(t, m) { return 1 - easeIn(1 - t, m); };
      eases['easeInOut' + name] = function(t, m) { return t < 0.5 ? easeIn(t * 2, m) / 2 : 1 - easeIn(t * -2 + 2, m) / 2; };
      eases['easeOutIn' + name] = function(t, m) { return t < 0.5 ? (1 - easeIn(1 - 2 * t, m)) / 2 : (easeIn(t * 2 - 1, m) + 1) / 2; };
    });
    eases.linear = function(t) { return t; };
    return eases;
  })();

  // Strings

  var numberToString = function(val) {
    return (is.str(val)) ? val : val + '';
  }

  var stringToHyphens = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
  }

  var selectString = function(str) {
    if (is.col(str)) return false;
    try {
      var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(str);
      return nodes;
    } catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Numbers

  var random = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  // Arrays

  var flattenArray = function(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.concat(is.arr(b) ? flattenArray(b) : b);
    }, []);
  }

  var toArray = function(o) {
    if (is.arr(o)) return o;
    if (is.str(o)) o = selectString(o) || o;
    if (o instanceof NodeList || o instanceof HTMLCollection) return [].slice.call(o);
    return [o];
  }

  var arrayContains = function(arr, val) {
    return arr.some(function(a) { return a === val; });
  }

  var groupArrayByProps = function(arr, propsArr) {
    var groups = {};
    arr.forEach(function(o) {
      var group = JSON.stringify(propsArr.map(function(p) { return o[p]; }));
      groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
      groups[group].push(o);
    });
    return Object.keys(groups).map(function(group) {
      return groups[group];
    });
  }

  var removeArrayDuplicates = function(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(item, pos, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item) === pos;
    });
  }

  // Objects

  var cloneObject = function(o) {
    var newObject = {};
    for (var p in o) newObject[p] = o[p];
    return newObject;
  }

  var mergeObjects = function(o1, o2) {
    for (var p in o2) o1[p] = !is.und(o1[p]) ? o1[p] : o2[p];
    return o1;
  }

  // Colors

  var hexToRgb = function(hex) {
    var rgx = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
    var hex = hex.replace(rgx, function(m, r, g, b) { return r + r + g + g + b + b; });
    var rgb = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    var r = parseInt(rgb[1], 16);
    var g = parseInt(rgb[2], 16);
    var b = parseInt(rgb[3], 16);
    return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
  }

  var hslToRgb = function(hsl) {
    var hsl = /hsl\((\d+),\s*([\d.]+)%,\s*([\d.]+)%\)/g.exec(hsl);
    var h = parseInt(hsl[1]) / 360;
    var s = parseInt(hsl[2]) / 100;
    var l = parseInt(hsl[3]) / 100;
    var hue2rgb = function(p, q, t) {
      if (t < 0) t += 1;
      if (t > 1) t -= 1;
      if (t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
      if (t < 1/2) return q;
      if (t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
      return p;
    }
    var r, g, b;
    if (s == 0) {
      r = g = b = l;
    } else {
      var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
      var p = 2 * l - q;
      r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
      g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
      b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
    }
    return 'rgb(' + r * 255 + ',' + g * 255 + ',' + b * 255 + ')';
  }

  var colorToRgb = function(val) {
    if (is.rgb(val)) return val;
    if (is.hex(val)) return hexToRgb(val);
    if (is.hsl(val)) return hslToRgb(val);
  }

  // Units

  var getUnit = function(val) {
    return /([\+\-]?[0-9|auto\.]+)(%|px|pt|em|rem|in|cm|mm|ex|pc|vw|vh|deg)?/.exec(val)[2];
  }

  var addDefaultTransformUnit = function(prop, val, intialVal) {
    if (getUnit(val)) return val;
    if (prop.indexOf('translate') > -1) return getUnit(intialVal) ? val + getUnit(intialVal) : val + 'px';
    if (prop.indexOf('rotate') > -1 || prop.indexOf('skew') > -1) return val + 'deg';
    return val;
  }

  // Values

  var getCSSValue = function(el, prop) {
    // First check if prop is a valid CSS property
    if (prop in el.style) {
      // Then return the property value or fallback to '0' when getPropertyValue fails
      return getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(stringToHyphens(prop)) || '0';
    }
  }

  var getTransformValue = function(el, prop) {
    var defaultVal = prop.indexOf('scale') > -1 ? 1 : 0;
    var str = el.style.transform;
    if (!str) return defaultVal;
    var rgx = /(\w+)\((.+?)\)/g;
    var match = [];
    var props = [];
    var values = [];
    while (match = rgx.exec(str)) {
      props.push(match[1]);
      values.push(match[2]);
    }
    var val = values.filter(function(f, i) { return props[i] === prop; });
    return val.length ? val[0] : defaultVal;
  }

  var getAnimationType = function(el, prop) {
    if ( is.dom(el) && arrayContains(validTransforms, prop)) return 'transform';
    if ( is.dom(el) && (el.getAttribute(prop) || (is.svg(el) && el[prop]))) return 'attribute';
    if ( is.dom(el) && (prop !== 'transform' && getCSSValue(el, prop))) return 'css';
    if (!is.nul(el[prop]) && !is.und(el[prop])) return 'object';
  }

  var getInitialTargetValue = function(target, prop) {
    switch (getAnimationType(target, prop)) {
      case 'transform': return getTransformValue(target, prop);
      case 'css': return getCSSValue(target, prop);
      case 'attribute': return target.getAttribute(prop);
    }
    return target[prop] || 0;
  }

  var getValidValue = function(values, val, originalCSS) {
    if (is.col(val)) return colorToRgb(val);
    if (getUnit(val)) return val;
    var unit = getUnit(values.to) ? getUnit(values.to) : getUnit(values.from);
    if (!unit && originalCSS) unit = getUnit(originalCSS);
    return unit ? val + unit : val;
  }

  var decomposeValue = function(val) {
    var rgx = /-?\d*\.?\d+/g;
    return {
      original: val,
      numbers: numberToString(val).match(rgx) ? numberToString(val).match(rgx).map(Number) : [0],
      strings: numberToString(val).split(rgx)
    }
  }

  var recomposeValue = function(numbers, strings, initialStrings) {
    return strings.reduce(function(a, b, i) {
      var b = (b ? b : initialStrings[i - 1]);
      return a + numbers[i - 1] + b;
    });
  }

  // Animatables

  var getAnimatables = function(targets) {
    var targets = targets ? (flattenArray(is.arr(targets) ? targets.map(toArray) : toArray(targets))) : [];
    return targets.map(function(t, i) {
      return { target: t, id: i };
    });
  }

  // Properties

  var getProperties = function(params, settings) {
    var props = [];
    for (var p in params) {
      if (!defaultSettings.hasOwnProperty(p) && p !== 'targets') {
        var prop = is.obj(params[p]) ? cloneObject(params[p]) : {value: params[p]};
        prop.name = p;
        props.push(mergeObjects(prop, settings));
      }
    }
    return props;
  }

  var getPropertiesValues = function(target, prop, value, i) {
    var values = toArray( is.fnc(value) ? value(target, i) : value);
    return {
      from: (values.length > 1) ? values[0] : getInitialTargetValue(target, prop),
      to: (values.length > 1) ? values[1] : values[0]
    }
  }

  // Tweens

  var getTweenValues = function(prop, values, type, target) {
    var valid = {};
    if (type === 'transform') {
      valid.from = prop + '(' + addDefaultTransformUnit(prop, values.from, values.to) + ')';
      valid.to = prop + '(' + addDefaultTransformUnit(prop, values.to) + ')';
    } else {
      var originalCSS = (type === 'css') ? getCSSValue(target, prop) : undefined;
      valid.from = getValidValue(values, values.from, originalCSS);
      valid.to = getValidValue(values, values.to, originalCSS);
    }
    return { from: decomposeValue(valid.from), to: decomposeValue(valid.to) };
  }

  var getTweensProps = function(animatables, props) {
    var tweensProps = [];
    animatables.forEach(function(animatable, i) {
      var target = animatable.target;
      return props.forEach(function(prop) {
        var animType = getAnimationType(target, prop.name);
        if (animType) {
          var values = getPropertiesValues(target, prop.name, prop.value, i);
          var tween = cloneObject(prop);
          tween.animatables = animatable;
          tween.type = animType;
          tween.from = getTweenValues(prop.name, values, tween.type, target).from;
          tween.to = getTweenValues(prop.name, values, tween.type, target).to;
          tween.round = (is.col(values.from) || tween.round) ? 1 : 0;
          tween.delay = (is.fnc(tween.delay) ? tween.delay(target, i, animatables.length) : tween.delay) / animation.speed;
          tween.duration = (is.fnc(tween.duration) ? tween.duration(target, i, animatables.length) : tween.duration) / animation.speed;
          tweensProps.push(tween);
        }
      });
    });
    return tweensProps;
  }

  var getTweens = function(animatables, props) {
    var tweensProps = getTweensProps(animatables, props);
    var splittedProps = groupArrayByProps(tweensProps, ['name', 'from', 'to', 'delay', 'duration']);
    return splittedProps.map(function(tweenProps) {
      var tween = cloneObject(tweenProps[0]);
      tween.animatables = tweenProps.map(function(p) { return p.animatables });
      tween.totalDuration = tween.delay + tween.duration;
      return tween;
    });
  }

  var reverseTweens = function(anim, delays) {
    anim.tweens.forEach(function(tween) {
      var toVal = tween.to;
      var fromVal = tween.from;
      var delayVal = anim.duration - (tween.delay + tween.duration);
      tween.from = toVal;
      tween.to = fromVal;
      if (delays) tween.delay = delayVal;
    });
    anim.reversed = anim.reversed ? false : true;
  }

  var getTweensDuration = function(tweens) {
    if (tweens.length) return Math.max.apply(Math, tweens.map(function(tween){ return tween.totalDuration; }));
  }

  var getTweensDelay = function(tweens) {
    if (tweens.length) return Math.min.apply(Math, tweens.map(function(tween){ return tween.delay; }));
  }

  // will-change

  var getWillChange = function(anim) {
    var props = [];
    var els = [];
    anim.tweens.forEach(function(tween) {
      if (tween.type === 'css' || tween.type === 'transform' ) {
        props.push(tween.type === 'css' ? stringToHyphens(tween.name) : 'transform');
        tween.animatables.forEach(function(animatable) { els.push(animatable.target); });
      }
    });
    return {
      properties: removeArrayDuplicates(props).join(', '),
      elements: removeArrayDuplicates(els)
    }
  }

  var setWillChange = function(anim) {
    var willChange = getWillChange(anim);
    willChange.elements.forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.willChange = willChange.properties;
    });
  }

  var removeWillChange = function(anim) {
    var willChange = getWillChange(anim);
    willChange.elements.forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.removeProperty('will-change');
    });
  }

  /* Svg path */

  var getPathProps = function(path) {
    var el = is.str(path) ? selectString(path)[0] : path;
    return {
      path: el,
      value: el.getTotalLength()
    }
  }

  var snapProgressToPath = function(tween, progress) {
    var pathEl = tween.path;
    var pathProgress = tween.value * progress;
    var point = function(offset) {
      var o = offset || 0;
      var p = progress > 1 ? tween.value + o : pathProgress + o;
      return pathEl.getPointAtLength(p);
    }
    var p = point();
    var p0 = point(-1);
    var p1 = point(+1);
    switch (tween.name) {
      case 'translateX': return p.x;
      case 'translateY': return p.y;
      case 'rotate': return Math.atan2(p1.y - p0.y, p1.x - p0.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
    }
  }

  // Progress

  var getTweenProgress = function(tween, time) {
    var elapsed = Math.min(Math.max(time - tween.delay, 0), tween.duration);
    var percent = elapsed / tween.duration;
    var progress = tween.to.numbers.map(function(number, p) {
      var start = tween.from.numbers[p];
      var eased = easings[tween.easing](percent, tween.elasticity);
      var val = tween.path ? snapProgressToPath(tween, eased) : start + eased * (number - start);
      val = tween.round ? Math.round(val * tween.round) / tween.round : val;
      return val;
    });
    return recomposeValue(progress, tween.to.strings, tween.from.strings);
  }

  var setAnimationProgress = function(anim, time) {
    var transforms;
    anim.currentTime = time;
    anim.progress = (time / anim.duration) * 100;
    for (var t = 0; t < anim.tweens.length; t++) {
      var tween = anim.tweens[t];
      tween.currentValue = getTweenProgress(tween, time);
      var progress = tween.currentValue;
      for (var a = 0; a < tween.animatables.length; a++) {
        var animatable = tween.animatables[a];
        var id = animatable.id;
        var target = animatable.target;
        var name = tween.name;
        switch (tween.type) {
          case 'css': target.style[name] = progress; break;
          case 'attribute': target.setAttribute(name, progress); break;
          case 'object': target[name] = progress; break;
          case 'transform':
          if (!transforms) transforms = {};
          if (!transforms[id]) transforms[id] = [];
          transforms[id].push(progress);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (transforms) {
      if (!transform) transform = (getCSSValue(document.body, transformStr) ? '' : '-webkit-') + transformStr;
      for (var t in transforms) {
        anim.animatables[t].target.style[transform] = transforms[t].join(' ');
      }
    }
  }

  // Animation

  var createAnimation = function(params) {
    var anim = {};
    anim.animatables = getAnimatables(params.targets);
    anim.settings = mergeObjects(params, defaultSettings);
    anim.properties = getProperties(params, anim.settings);
    anim.tweens = getTweens(anim.animatables, anim.properties);
    anim.duration = getTweensDuration(anim.tweens) || params.duration;
    anim.delay = getTweensDelay(anim.tweens) || params.delay;
    anim.currentTime = 0;
    anim.progress = 0;
    anim.ended = false;
    return anim;
  }

  // Public

  var animations = [];
  var raf = 0;

  var engine = (function() {
    var play = function() { raf = requestAnimationFrame(step); };
    var step = function(t) {
      if (animations.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) animations[i].tick(t);
        play();
      } else {
        cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
        raf = 0;
      }
    }
    return play;
  })();

  var animation = function(params) {

    var anim = createAnimation(params);
    var time = {};

    anim.tick = function(now) {
      anim.ended = false;
      if (!time.start) time.start = now;
      time.current = Math.min(Math.max(time.last + now - time.start, 0), anim.duration);
      setAnimationProgress(anim, time.current);
      var s = anim.settings;
      if (time.current >= anim.delay) {
        if (s.begin) s.begin(anim); s.begin = undefined;
        if (s.update) s.update(anim);
      }
      if (time.current >= anim.duration) {
        if (s.loop) {
          time.start = now;
          if (s.direction === 'alternate') reverseTweens(anim, true);
          if (is.num(s.loop)) s.loop--;
        } else {
          anim.ended = true;
          anim.pause();
          if (s.complete) s.complete(anim);
        }
        time.last = 0;
      }
    }

    anim.seek = function(progress) {
      setAnimationProgress(anim, (progress / 100) * anim.duration);
    }

    anim.pause = function() {
      removeWillChange(anim);
      var i = animations.indexOf(anim);
      if (i > -1) animations.splice(i, 1);
    }

    anim.play = function(params) {
      anim.pause();
      if (params) anim = mergeObjects(createAnimation(mergeObjects(params, anim.settings)), anim);
      time.start = 0;
      time.last = anim.ended ? 0 : anim.currentTime;
      var s = anim.settings;
      if (s.direction === 'reverse') reverseTweens(anim);
      if (s.direction === 'alternate' && !s.loop) s.loop = 1;
      setWillChange(anim);
      animations.push(anim);
      if (!raf) engine();
    }

    anim.restart = function() {
      if (anim.reversed) reverseTweens(anim);
      anim.pause();
      anim.seek(0);
      anim.play();
    }

    if (anim.settings.autoplay) anim.play();

    return anim;

  }

  // Remove one or multiple targets from all active animations.

  var remove = function(elements) {
    var targets = flattenArray(is.arr(elements) ? elements.map(toArray) : toArray(elements));
    for (var i = animations.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var animation = animations[i];
      var tweens = animation.tweens;
      for (var t = tweens.length-1; t >= 0; t--) {
        var animatables = tweens[t].animatables;
        for (var a = animatables.length-1; a >= 0; a--) {
          if (arrayContains(targets, animatables[a].target)) {
            animatables.splice(a, 1);
            if (!animatables.length) tweens.splice(t, 1);
            if (!tweens.length) animation.pause();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  animation.version = version;
  animation.speed = 1;
  animation.list = animations;
  animation.remove = remove;
  animation.easings = easings;
  animation.getValue = getInitialTargetValue;
  animation.path = getPathProps;
  animation.random = random;

  return animation;

}));

var path = anime.path('path');

anime({
  targets: 'div',
  translateX: path,
  translateY: path,
  rotate: path,
  duration: 3000,
  loop: true,
  easing: 'linear'
});

anime({
  targets: 'path',
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 6000,
  loop: true,
  direction: 'alternate',
  easing: 'easeInOutExpo'
});
```

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Circular';
 src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1137/Circular-Book.woff') format('woff');
 font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Circular';
 src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1137/Circular-Bold.woff') format('woff');
 font-weight: bold;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
 background: #18212D;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: white;
 font-family: 'Circular', 'sans-serif';
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 max-width: 18rem;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

a {
  color: #206EFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer span {
  opacity: .5;
}

.logo img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 16px;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 8rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.red {
  background-color: #FF324A;
}

.green {
  background-color: #31FFA6;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #206EFF;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: #FFFF99;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: .5rem;
  left: .5rem;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <svg width="256" height="112" viewBox="0 0 256 112">
      <path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" d="M8,56 C8,33.90861 25.90861,16 48,16 C70.09139,16 88,33.90861 88,56 C88,78.09139 105.90861,92 128,92 C150.09139,92 160,72 160,56 C160,40 148,24 128,24 C108,24 96,40 96,56 C96,72 105.90861,92 128,92 C154,93 168,78 168,56 C168,33.90861 185.90861,16 208,16 C230.09139,16 248,33.90861 248,56 C248,78.09139 230.09139,96 208,96 L48,96 C25.90861,96 8,78.09139 8,56 Z"/>
    </svg>
    <div class="green"></div>
  </article>
  <footer>
    <span>Made with</span> <a href="http://anime-js.com">anime.js</a>
  </footer>
  <a class="logo" href="http://anime-js.com"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1137/anime-logo.png"></img></a>
</section>
```

---

#### attribution

<sup>*Code copied from This pen on Code pen https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/dXNgVB*</sup>

Comment: Sagar V you're absolutely right. I had som issues wrapping my head around what the files were etc. etc. But I finally made it work. You deserve more than my tiny upvote. Thank you so much.